# Active storage problem - replacing pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-activestorage

I'm using:
`ruby 2.6`
`rails 6.1.4`
`devise`
`devise_token_auth`
`active-storage` usingl locally disk service

I'm creating api in which I can storage and upload pictures. I can upload pic via Insomnia but problem is when I want to add second image to the same user. Image is just replacing.

`user.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  
  def initialize
    self.pictures = []
  end

  extend Devise::Models #added this line to extend devise model
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX= /^(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/ix
  validates :username, presence: true, length: {minimum:3, maximum:26},
            format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX, :multiline => true,
            message: :invalid_username }
  validate :password_complexity

  attr_accessor :pictures

  has_many_attached :pictures
  validates :pictures, content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'],
            size: { less_than: 5.megabytes , message: :invalid_size }

  def password_complexity
    return if password.blank? || password =~ /^((?!.*[\s]))/
    errors.add :password, :invalid_password
  end
end
```

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters        
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:pictures, :username, :email])
    end
end
```

All controllers which I use are default from `devise_token_auth`. I found tip to add in `config/application.rb`

```
 config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

but after that I'm always getting `status 500`

[image: insomnia error]

Answer (score 1):

Did you add an array to the parameter so you can store multiple image ?

```
def configure_permitted_parameters        
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:pictures [], :username, :email])
    end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated code at the topic (user.rb and added app controller). Unfortuntely now I've got error: "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `attached?' for #<String:0x0000555f02239298>>"

Comment: In your application controller you have to add an array to your parameter so you can store multiple images. I am updating the answer so you can see.

Comment: @lucas_grandviergne `#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)>`. In Insomnia after that error I changed json `"pictures":` into `"pictures []"` but it doesn't work. How I can give these arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by adding this to the config/environment/development.rb (as per the Rails Guide):

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to open application.rb and inside your module add.

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

That is all you need to do. It works, Just make sure you save all your files, and restart your server.

You can see in the rails docs it says the following:

> Optionally replace existing files instead of adding to them when assigning to a collection of attachments (as in @user.update!(images: [ … ])). Use config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many to control this behavior.

[Rails Guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html#active-storage-notable-changes)